# Error when accessing pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a PivotTable in Excel that looks like this:

```
Account                e-mail   Sum of Price    Sum of Billing Price
Customer Z             blah@gmail.com       30            33.75
Customer Z Total                            30            33.75
Customer Y             blah@gmail.com       10            10.5
Customer Y Total                            10            10.5
Grand Total                                 40              44.25
```

I have the following VBA Code:

```
For j = 2 To pt.RowFields(1).PivotItems.Count
    Sheets("Configuration").Range("j2").Value = Sheets("Configuration").Range("j2").Value + 1

    Client = pt.RowFields("Account").PivotItems(j)
    sum = pt.GetPivotData("Sum Of Billing Price", "Account", Client)
    net = pt.GetPivotData("Sum Of Price", "Account", Client)
    email = pt.RowFields("e-mail").PivotItems(j)
    ...
```

When I run the code, I receive the error: `Unable To Get PivotItems Property Of PivotField Class` when assigning the value to e-mail. Assigning the value to Client works as expected. I have also tried using index numbers, with same result.

Comment: Providing Excel version would be nice. Have you tried the column name without a dash?

Comment: excel 2012 and 2013. yes I have

Comment: the count of pivotitems in the first row field is unlikely to be the same as for the second field and there is no relationship between the two anyway. for what you seem to be doing I would suggest looping through the table range rather than the pivotitems

Comment: it turned out to be that vba could not handle duplicate e-mail addresses!?!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have emails in every row. You may want to put a conditional statement in to deal with this.

Comment: that's just because the total row is expanded. :) don't think this will help. but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem turned out to be that VBA could not handle duplicate e-mail addresses. Change one of the e-mail addresses by one character and it works fine.

Comment: that is purely coincidental because you now have two items in each and they happen to be in the same order-you should not expect it to work in a typical pivot table